# Date time in two rows in Italian format and time zone

Tags: babel, datetime, datetime2

I have now created this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=4cm,draw=red!60,circle,line width=2mm] {\large\textbf{\DTMnow}};
\node at (0,1) (A) {\textcolor{Green}{\Large \faCheckCircle}};
\node at (0,-1) (B) {\large \textsc{Approved}};
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

with this output:

[image]

Using `datetime2` package, how I can this italian date structure?

[image]

Comment: You can use `\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}` to change the date from "year-month-day"  to "day-month-year". How exactly should the "time"  part look like?

Comment: Is this the output you want to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Sxr.png

Comment: @leandriis Very kind hours, minutes and seconds in Italian time. Thank you for your interest.....For your 2nd comment the image it is perfect!

Comment: So, basically like the following? https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFsb3.png

Comment: @leandriis Perfect! Here in Italy are the 23:23 (pm).

Comment: For all users: I have the another hour in Italy :-( +2 UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this is not the most elegant solution, but you can use `\DTMtoday` and `\DTMcurrenttime` instead of `\DTMnow` and add the options `text width=3cm` and `align=center` to your node. In order to change the date format, you can use `\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}`. If you also want to get rid of the seconds, add the package option `showseconds=false` to the `datetime2` package.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=4cm,
                 draw=red!60,
                 circle,
                 line width=2mm, 
                 text width=3cm,
                 align=center] 
                 {\large \bfseries \mbox{\DTMtoday} \DTMcurrenttime};
\node at (0,1) (A) {\textcolor{Green}{\Large \faCheckCircle}};
\node at (0,-1) (B) {\large \textsc{Approved}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is another version using the `italian` localization module.

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm,italian]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[useregional=numeric,showseconds=true,showzone=false]{datetime2}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=4cm,
                 draw=red!60,
                 circle,
                 line width=2mm, 
                 text width=3cm,
                 align=center] 
                 {\large \bfseries \mbox{\DTMtoday} \DTMcurrenttime};
\node at (0,1) (A) {\textcolor{Green}{\Large \faCheckCircle}};
\node at (0,-1) (B) {\large \textsc{Approved}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Why is it not elegant solution? Why I have 21:27 like a time instead of 23:27?

Comment: I have put the `\usepackage[showseconds=true]{datetime2}`  and not false, and now I see the seconds :-)...but the hour in Italy is 23:56. But it's not that I have the wrong time zone? :-) :-) How fix it?

Comment: @Sebastiano - Is your system maybe configured to show GMT (Greenwich mean time) instead of local time? Or is it just a coincidence that the difference between the two times is currently 2 hours?

Comment: @Sebastiano: Regarding the seconds not showing up: Which compiler did you use to compile the example document? I used PDFLaTeX and get the seconds by default. With XeLaTeX on the other hand, seconds are omitted by default and can be shown upon using the `showseconds=true` package option.

Comment: @leandriis Hi. Last night I went to sleep at 1:30 am reading the manual and I have make many compilations. I had tried also with singolar option or double options for the `datatime2` without a solution. I have understood only a few minutes ago that the reason of the hour in Italy is not to have used my updated `MikTeX` but `Papeeria`, an online editor more fast of `MikTeX` on this OS W7 32-bit. `Papeeria` use `TeXlive2019`. I often use `pdfLaTeX` and very very few the others engines. However your solution it is correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jsol.png :-( excuse very much.

Comment: @Mico Hi to you too.Unfortunately I had read the manual so many times that I couldn't set the Italian time zone :-( GMT+1. Thank you very much for your support.