# A professional stamp in relief

Tags: tikz-pgf, datetime2, tikzlibrary

Related to these previous my questions [A special annulment (i.e., cancellation) of a stamp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566151/a-special-annulment-i-e-cancellation-of-a-stamp) and [Date time in two rows in Italian format and time zone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567244/date-time-in-two-rows-in-italian-format-and-time-zone) I have created another MWE to have some different choices and a more professional timbre.

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm,italian]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[useregional=numeric,showseconds=true,showzone=false]{datetime2}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[minimum size=4cm,
                 draw=black,
                 circle,
                 line width=.5mm, 
                 text width=3cm,
                 align=center] 
                 {\large \bfseries \mbox{\DTMtoday} \DTMcurrenttime};
\draw [black,line width=.35mm] (0,0) circle[radius=1.75cm];
                 {\large \bfseries \mbox{\DTMtoday} \DTMcurrenttime};            
\node at (0,1) (A) {\textcolor{Green}{\large Visto}};
\node at (0,-1) (B) {\small \textsc{Non approvato}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would to have

[image: https://i1.wp.com/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61aM4kg3x2L.AC_SL1000.jpg?resize=840%2C840&ssl=1]

the circumferences in relief, deleting "non approvato" and "visto" in the middle part, putting them between the two circumferences.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53369/how-to-create-text-with-shadows

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi, :-) thank you for the link..I am not able to make a relief and put the text into two circumferences :-(

Comment: The pointer may provide an approach for the appearance of relief text, perhaps.  But the circumference writing is clearly a `tikz` thing, not addressed in the referenced question.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I thought the question was clear. Now I edit my question. Thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvJew.png

Comment: @leandriis Yes :-) I smile when you send me the previews :-) :-) The image was all with the black background but I think it's with a transparent option your code. Does the relief stand up?

Comment: @Sebastiano: I completely missed the part of the relief like text. I just focused on getting the text to follow the curve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With quite a lot of help from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545988/87678, it's possible to come up with something that looks a bit like your picture. You could further tweak the various settings to your liking.

It's pretty slow to compile though! It would probably be quicker, easier, and nicer looking to to script something with ImageMagick.

```
\documentclass[italian]{standalone}
\usepackage[useregional=numeric,showseconds=true,showzone=false]{datetime2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, shadows.blur}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowangle}{132}
\newlength{\shadowdistance}
\pgfmathsetlength{\shadowdistance}{0.3pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowopacity}{0.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowspread}{0.02}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowsize}{0}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\totshadow}{100}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    datetime/.style={
      align=center,
      font=\scriptsize\sffamily\bfseries
    },
    pathtext/.style={
      opacity={\shadowopacity/\totshadow},
      shift={({\shadowangle-180}:\shadowdistance)},
      scale={1+\shadowsize}
    },
    pathblur/.style={
      fill=white,
      blur shadow={%
        shadow xshift=0.3pt,
        shadow yshift=-0.3pt,
        shadow scale=1,
        shadow blur radius=1.5pt
      }
    }
  ]
  \path [use as bounding box] (-45pt,-45pt) rectangle (45pt,45pt);
  \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
    \path [pathblur] (0,0) circle (26pt) circle (24pt); 
    \path [pathblur] (0,0) circle (41pt) circle (39pt); 
  \end{scope}
  \foreach \nshadow [evaluate=\nshadow as \angshadow using \nshadow/\totshadow*360] in {1,...,\totshadow}{
    \path[pathtext,
      rotate=-90,
      postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          transform={shift=(\angshadow:\shadowspread)},
          text effects along path,
          text effects/every character/.style={text along path},
          text effects/font = {\sffamily\bfseries},
          text align/align=center,
          raise=-7pt, 
          reverse path=true,
          text={VISTO}
        }
      }
    ] (0,0) circle (36pt);}
  \path[
      rotate=-90,
      postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          text effects along path,
          text effects/every character/.style={text along path},
          text effects/font = {\sffamily\bfseries},
          text align/align=center,
          raise=-7pt, 
          reverse path=true,
          text effects/color=white,
          text={VISTO}
        }
      }
    ] (0,0) circle (36pt);
  \foreach \nshadow [evaluate=\nshadow as \angshadow using \nshadow/\totshadow*360] in {1,...,\totshadow}{
    \path[pathtext,
      rotate=90,
      postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          transform={shift=(\angshadow:\shadowspread)},
          text effects along path,
          text effects/every character/.style={text along path},
          text effects/font = {\sffamily\bfseries},
          text align/align=center,
          text={NON APPROVATO}
        }
      }
    ] (0,0) circle (36pt);}
  \path[
      rotate=90,
      postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          text effects along path,
          text effects/every character/.style={text along path},
          text effects/font = {\sffamily\bfseries},
          text align/align=center,
          text effects/color=white,
          text={NON APPROVATO}
        }
      }
    ] (0,0) circle (36pt);
  \path[pathtext]
    foreach \nshadow [evaluate=\nshadow as \angshadow using \nshadow/\totshadow*360] in {1,...,\totshadow}
      {node [datetime] at (\angshadow:\shadowspread) {\DTMtoday\\\DTMcurrenttime}};
  \node [datetime, text=white] {\DTMtoday\\\DTMcurrenttime};
  \path [pathblur] (25:32.5pt) circle (2pt); 
  \path [pathblur] (155:32.5pt) circle (2pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1 Very nice job !

Comment: Sorry for the delay but having 6 classes and with so many commitments I was not able to connect. Thank you very much. I would not have been able to do it even after 1 a.l. Thank you very much David.