# Stamp with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a signature stamp with Tikz in order to put them on each page of my documents but I can't really do it.

Here is a sketch of what I want.
(the two identical figures on the sketch are stars :D).
[image]

This is what I tried to do :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfornament,tikzrput}         
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Dessin des cercles extérieurs
\draw[ultra thick, red] circle[radius=3cm] circle[radius=3.5cm];
\draw[line width=2mm, red] circle[radius=3.7cm];

% Texte entre les cercles
\path 
    [rotate=210,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|}, text={ Something {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt]{15}} Name here {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt]{15}}},
      text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
     circle[radius=3.2cm]; 

% Étoiles
\rput{-20}(1.5,2.6){\pgfornament[scale=.2, color=red]{87}}
\rput{20}(-1.5,2.6){\pgfornament[scale=.2, color=red]{87}} 
\rput{90}(0,-2.6){\pgfornament[scale=.2, color=red]{87}}

% Texte central
\rput(0,0){ABCD}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get this time

[image]

Comment: I had seen this code but impossible to compile it on Overleaf

Comment: Your example compiles on Overleaf, TeX Live 2023 + pdflatex.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567955/a-professional-stamp-in-relief this code doesn't compile on Overleaf, TeX Live 2023 + pdflatex.

Comment: Hmm I see that example in the linked question does compile on Overleaf, TeX Live 2023 + pdflatex. Did you try "Recompile from scratch"? What errors do you experience?

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.28)  22 MAR 2024 13:27